# Software which detects Internet usage by an EXE?

Tags: windows, data-visualization, network-monitor, internet

Sometimes my router shows huge Internet usage by my Windows laptop, but I am unaware of the reason.

I want to be sure that it's not infected with a virus. Is there software which can detect which EXE is using the Internet and how much data transfer it is doing?

Comment: The search term "outbound firewall" is relevant.  Rules can be set to prevent unwanted outbound traffic by rogue processes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use Windows Vista or later versions, you don't need to install any additional software to see the processes with network activity, Windows comes with [Resource Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor). You just need to have been the Windows task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd>) and click on resource monitor:

[image]

In the "network" tab you can see the processes with network activity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I believe that you can get this information from [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It is a free download from Microsoft, (originally by  Sysinternals), as it can let you see which process(es) are performing the most network traffic.

You could also take a look at [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  [This story](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/10/30/3529266.aspx) is well worth a read as well.

*(Sorry can't include any screenshots at the moment as I am running Linux rather than Windows)*

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/manual/?lang=English). It monitors IP traffic from your computer and will keep logs on a per process basis, it is also free.

Unlike most of the other suggestions, this utility logs usage over time, not just a real-time view of current usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows XP or before, you can use [Sygate Personal Firewall](http://download.cnet.com/Sygate-Personal-Firewall/3000-2092_4-10049526.html) by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sygate_Technologies:

- Free to try; $39.95 to buy
- Windows 95/NT/98/Me/2000/XP
- Very lightweight (~10 MB of RAM)
- You can see the processes with network activity and block specific .exe from accessing Internet.

[image]

For the background story, Sygate Personal Firewall got bought and killed by Symantec (Norton), so was never made available for Windows 7 (still works great on XP though). And PC Tools Firewall had the same fate (bought and killed AGAIN by Symantec), only a bit later so I could run it on Windows 7, until it eventually broke (seems like it works with Windows 7 RTM but not with Windows 7 SP1).